# Commond anode led driver

Tags: led-matrix

I need to drive a bunch of 7-segments and 14-segments led display (in total, 105 LEDs with common anode).

I bought an HT16K33 to drive them, but did not take into account the common cathode requirement...

I can't manage to find any chip that could drive them correctly. I need an I2C interface with at least three addresses, 105 LEDs minimum. Dimming and Blinking feature would be great but are not required for my project.

I also thought I could invert the signal from the HT16K33 output, but I'm not sure this is a good idea...

Any help on that ?

Answer (score 0):

It is designed for common cathode (CC) LEDs not CA.  You need to get the right LEDs.  Since Nch FETs are better with sink RdsOn, this why the topology for CC.

Alternatively lookup the right driver for CA.

http://www.mouser.com/catalog/645/usd/89.pdf

Comment: I've already searched in this file. The best I can find is the MAX6956 that can drive up to 28 LEDs. This is far from the 16x8 that offers the HT16k33...

Comment: Then CC LEDs are the answer.